# is there a really simple and reliable way to create a unique lock (file) on linux? without using `flock`

Tags: lock, flock

EDIT: I learned how to use flock for exclusive lock and how to not mess with it: https://superuser.com/questions/1619940/flock-is-randomly-failing-on-desktop-pc-but-not-on-notebook-could-be-defectiv/. I think this question is unecessary as there is no need to use anything else than flock. But... "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?" I wont delete this question to not mess my account. If left here may also help ppl to understand and use flock. Feel free to delete it tho.

---

OLD UNNECESSARY QUESTION

For example: I want to create a file lock to prevent a simultaneous backup attempt of the same file, that is run every time I start a new terminal, like on guake that can start several named tabs simultaneously.

I do not want to use `flock`. I have extreme difficulty understanding and trying to use it :(

I think the biggest problem is `flock -x asdf.txt` where asdf.txt is a real existing file, and it gives "flock: bad file descriptor: 'asdf.txt'" and that feels like a not user friendly implementation. I got that example from the man page and I am stuck again. It feels like I am not being able to explain the problem, but the problem is on my test case (answer): I need a file lock to do things exclusively, and I always have a hard time trying to do that with flock...

Comment: The simple and reiable way is to use `flock`. There are examples in the man page. You don't have to understand how they work. If you don't understand how to use them in your code, post your code, explain what you want to do and where you're stuck.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', I've been using symlinks, as on my answer. So there is a test case on it. For some reason whenever I try to look at flock examples I get confused. And I really like to understand what I am coding so I can modify at will by myself :)

Comment: learned how to use flock for exclusive lock and how to not mess with it: https://superuser.com/questions/1619940/flock-is-randomly-failing-on-desktop-pc-but-not-on-notebook-could-be-defectiv/. I think this question is unecessary as there is no need to use anything else than flock.

Comment: "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?" I wont delete this question to not mess my account. If left here may also help ppl to understand and use flock. Feel free to delete it tho.

Comment: It would be even better if you could post an answer with what you found.

Comment: @terdon I found that I was breaking the lock (that was the self script file) because the editor was creating a new file/inode https://superuser.com/questions/1619940/flock-is-randomly-failing-on-desktop-pc-but-not-on-notebook-could-be-defectiv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use four shellscript commands: pexlock, pshlock, punlock, and pcllock from [ShellShoccar-jpn/misc-tools](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/misc-tools); exclusive lock and shared lock are realized with `(set -C; :>filename)` and `mkdir` respectively, so it's useful for not only GNU/Linux, but also for any other POSIX environment.

Comment: and it also has a kind of "wrapper" `exflock` :)

Answer (score -1):

I've been using just a symlink creation retry, like this:

```
while true;do
  if ln -s "/a/b/c/myExisingRealFile.ext" /tmp/myFileSymlink.lock 2>/dev/null;then
    : #do something
    rm /tmp/myFileSymlink.lock
    break
  fi
done
```

tested with (bash) myLockTest.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "the idea is: after every OK must always follow a single REMOVED"
echo "so also no subsequent OKs."

echo >/tmp/tstMyScript.sh;
export strLock="/tmp/tstUniqueLock.lock";
rm -v "$strLock" 2>/dev/null;

trap -- "echo EXIT;rm -v "$strLock"" EXIT
trap -- "echo INT;rm -v "$strLock"" INT

FUNClock(){ 
 n=0;
 while true;do 
  if ln -s "/tmp/tstMyScript.sh" "$strLock" 2>/dev/null;then 
   echo "$n:$BASHPID:ok";
   rm -v "$strLock"; 
   break;
  fi;
  echo "$n:$BASHPID:retry:$((++n))";
  sleep 0.25
 done;
};export -f FUNClock;
for((i=0;i<100;i++));do FUNClock&:;done # lower from 100 to 1 if you are unsure, then increase slowly
```

If there are other simple and easy to understand and use ways, I would like to know!

Comment: actually, for a backup test case (that should be once per session), I do not use a retry loop, just a skip attempt.

Comment: There are several obvious bugs in this implementation. It doesn't clean up after itself if it's interrupted (the lock remains taken, even after a reset). It uses a tight loop if the lock is taken (it's a spinlock, which is only suitable for critical sections with a small, bounded duration on multiprocessor systems).

Comment: oh ok, I could use bash's `trap -- "rm ..." INT` and a few others may be. There could have an option for a lock cleanup too. To prevent the spinlock I think it would be enough to add a `sleep 0.25` on the loop right?

Comment: I think, if there was a wrapper script to `flock` that does what I need on my testcase loop, it could be a more reliable solution I guess? So, I would not need to understand flock, just use that script.

Comment: Why would you want a wrapper script to `flock`? What do you expect that wrapper script to do other than just call `flock`? There's an example in the man page where you just have to fill in `# ... commands executed under lock ...`. Where are you having trouble copying that example?

Comment: I think the biggest problem is `flock -x asdf.txt` where asdf.txt is a real existing file, and it gives "flock: bad file descriptor: 'asdf.txt'" and that feels like a not user friendly implementation. I got that example from the man page and I am stuck again. It feels like I am not being able to explain the problem, but the problem is on my test case: I need a file lock to do things exclusively, and I always have a hard time trying to do that with flock...

Comment: There's nothing like `flock -x asdf.txt` in the man page… You should delete this question and instead ask a question that contains your existing code that works without a lock, and explain what part is the critical section and ask how to put a lock around it. Without arbitrarily rejecting the sane solution.